# Not getting drop down populated

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to populate a drop down list from a class but I get an unexpected result. I am trying to set Id and Name in the drop down text and value respectively.

item.java

```
  package com;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Item {

    public List<Types> getItems() {
        List<Types> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Types t = new Types();
            t.setId(i + "");
            t.setName(i + "");
            list.add(t);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public class Types {

        public String Id;
        public String Name;

        public String getId() {
            return Id;
        }

        public void setId(String Id) {
            this.Id = Id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }

        public void setName(String Name) {
            this.Name = Name;
        }
     }
     }
```

jsp file

```
 <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <jsp:useBean id="list" class="com.Item"/>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${list.items}">
                <option value="">${item}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

result page source

```
<select>     
<option value="">com.Item$Types@781ac014</option>      
...
</select>
```

Comment: try `${item.name}` instead

Comment: Yes. That was missing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here  item=Type object

that is the reason its printed as object value

if you want to print the attribute
  then obj.attributename

here item.name